# Validating number of failing Junits in ANT

Tags: ant, junit

I would like to run a JUnit regression Test Suite from within an ANT build script. The test suite has a known number of failures which we are working towards fixing. I want the build to *fail* if the number of failing tests increases (or changes at all if that's easier to code) - this value can be hard coded in the ANT script.

I'm looking for details on how to implement this.

Comment: What's the point of running unit tests which are known to fail? As you may know, this is against the best practice which is to keep 100% of unit tests passing all the time - and if a test fails, either fix it right away, or disable/remove it if it can't be fixed.

Comment: Good point but this is actually a regression test suite which contains 'known' failures. In time I hope these will be fixed, but at the moment we've just got around to documenting them and want to make sure we don't introduce more failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The junit task creates and XML file with the failing tests.  There's no reason you couldn't use [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) to count the number of failures and have a conditional fail if that value is too high.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I'm a bit late to the party:

Another option would be to use JUnit 4 and annotate the failing tests with @Ignore.

That way they will not run, and not count as failures, but the number of ignored tests will still be printed, reminding you there is work left to do.

If a test fails for the first time, you'll get a regular failure; then you can decide whether to fix or to ignore it.

More information:

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/31983/1954

Comment: Thanks for your response. I hadn't encountered that annotation. Unfortunately, because I am using parametrized tests, I only want to ignore certain tests for certain parameters - I don't think JUnit is flexible enough to do this.

Comment: Yes, apparently you cannot "@Ignore" just some parameters. You could comment out the failing values, and create a placeholder test that is "@Ignored", so you remember the failing values. That way you don't need to count tests...